# Quicksort algorithm without data type

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, pascal

Most implementations of quicksort deal with sorting an array of **integers**.  Thus, in a language with fixed data types, such as Pascal, one is required to modify the algorithm in order to sort other arrays, such as arrays of **strings**.

This is of course an easy task, requiring only minor modifications, besides implementing the order relation on the set of values our array is suppose to take.  However it would be desirable to have a one-size-fits-all implementation.

My question is thus:

> Question: Is it possible to write a "Quicksort Pascal Unit" which could be used to sort any array, be it of integers, strings or whatever?

The main difficulty one needs to address is that the unit will not have access to the data type of the matrix entries.

Comment: No. Pascal is strongly-typed. The only way to do this without knowing the type ahead of time would be to use variants (which require a lot of overhead) or generics (again involving considerable overhead). Either of those alternatives would increase the memory footprint and slow the sort, which defeats the entire puipose of quicksort. Modern Pascal allows you to overload functions, which would allow you to put an implementation of each datatype's QS in the same unit, use the same name, and let the compiler determine which to use based on the parameters, but that's about it.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't know about Pascal generics but I think that the overhead should not be that bad for most applications.

Comment: @Phil1970: They are, at least in Delphi, both in the amount of code that is generated and in the execution speed. FreePascal's generics implementation appears to be worse than Delphi's, so I'd suspect the additional overhead exists there as well.

Comment: If you google `fpc generic "quicksort"`, you'll find that the top several hits include a generic quicksort.  If you are concerned about execution speed, I think you'll need to do your own benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite for mentioning variants and generics, which I am sure can do the job, but my question was more on the theorethical side, regarding whether or not quicksort can be implemented in a strongly-typed language (not necessarily just Pascal) while not knowing the type of the matrix entries.  I think I found a nice answer which I am going to post below.

Comment: I don't know what variant of Pascal you're using, but some versions (like Free Pascal) support an untyped pointer (like `void *` in C). With that, you could easily write a function similar to the C library's [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm).

Comment: Hi @JimMischel , indeed I am using Free Pascal, but I wouldn't like to abuse of pointers as that kind of defeats the purpose of the question in which the fixed data type is given.  In fact I would be happy to use pointers as much as needed in the implementation of `qsort`, as long as the calling program does not have to refer to pointers too many times.  It would be great to call `qsort` with the command `qsort(array_to_be_sorted, num_of_entries, sizeof_array_entry, @comparison_function)`, in which the parameters of `comparison_function` are matrix indices, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @JimMischel, I guess I can do as you said, although my comparison
function must take untyped variables, rather than matrix indices, so
that in its body one should declare new typed (absolute) variables on
top of the untyped ones to take advantage of existing functions dealing
with the type of the matrix entries.  An example for integer matrices
would be `function less(var x,y): boolean; var x1: integer absolute x;
y1: integer absolute y; begin less:= x1 < y1; end;`

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Asking a question often sets out a mental process that quickly leads to the answer, and here is one I just found and with which I am very happy.

The main point is to realize that the quicksort algorithm only needs to know the type of the matrix entries in order to:

- compare, and
- swap

them.  Thus, if you provide alternative means for these tasks to be performed, quicksort will be happy enough.

In order to do this one declares a "function type" `orderRel` which takes two integers (thought to be the indices of the matrix entries to be compared) and a "procedure type" `copierProc` (also taking two indices, and meant to copy one matrix entry into another. See code below).

The quicksort unit is then implemented exclusively in terms of these subroutines, while the calling program is left with the task of implementing the  `orderRel` and `copierProc` in full view of the data type, which it obviously knows.  These two **subroutines** are then passed to quicksort as **parameters**.

Here is the full implementation of the quicksort unit and you will find a complete testing program below.  Both were tested in "Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.4+dfsg-18ubuntu2 [2018/08/29] for x86_64".

```
{$R+}

unit Quicksort;

interface

type
  orderRel = function(i, j: longint): boolean;                (* Order relation for sorting *)
  copierProc = procedure(i, j: longint);                      (* Used to copy matrix entry i to entry j *)

procedure qsort(n: longint; less: orderRel; cp: copierProc);  (* Quicksort takes two functions as arguments *)

implementation

procedure qsort(n: longint; less: orderRel; cp: copierProc);

  var left, rght: longint;

  procedure qsort1(a, b: longint);
  begin
  cp((a+b) div 2, n+1); (* Position n+1 of the matrix used as pivot *)
  left:= a; rght:= b;
  while left <= rght do begin
    while less(left, n+1) do inc(left);
    while less(n+1, rght) do dec(rght);
    if left <= rght then begin
      cp(left, n+2); cp(rght, left); cp(n+2, rght); (* Position n+2 used as auxiliar variable for swapping *)
      inc(left); dec(rght);
      end;
    end;
  if left < b then qsort1(left, b);
  if a < rght then qsort1(a, rght);
  end;

begin
qsort1(1,n);
end;

end.
```

Here is the test program:

```
program Test; (* For testing unit quicksort *)

uses quicksort;

const
  N = 9;

(* Matrices to be sorted.  One of integers, the other of strings *)

var
  int_arr:  array[1..N+2] of integer; (* Quicksort needs two extra working slots, hence N+2 *)
  st_arr:   array[1..N+2] of string;

(* Next two subroutines to be fed to Quicksort when sorting integer matrices *)

function int_comparisson (i, j: longint): boolean;
begin
int_comparisson:= int_arr[i] < int_arr[j];
end;

procedure int_copy(i, j: longint);
begin
int_arr[j]:= int_arr[i];
end;

(* Next two subroutines to be fed to Quicksort when sorting matrices of strings *)

function st_comparisson(i, j: longint): boolean;
begin
st_comparisson:= st_arr[i] < st_arr[j];
end;

procedure st_copy(i, j: longint);
begin
st_arr[j]:= st_arr[i];
end;

var
  i: integer;

begin

(* Initialize integer matrix *)
for i:= 1 to N do int_arr[i]:= random(100);

qsort(N, @int_comparisson, @int_copy); (* Quicksort takes two functions as arguments *)

for i:= 1 to N do write(int_arr[i]:5);
writeln;

(* Initialize matrix of strings *)
st_arr[1]:= 'the';
st_arr[2]:= 'quick';
st_arr[3]:= 'brown';
st_arr[4]:= 'fox';
st_arr[5]:= 'jumps';
st_arr[6]:= 'over';
st_arr[7]:= 'the';
st_arr[8]:= 'lazy';
st_arr[9]:= 'dog';

qsort(N, @st_comparisson, @st_copy);

for i:= 1 to N do write(st_arr[i], ' '); writeln;

end.
```

PS: Besides comparing and swaping, quicksort actually also needs to
store a pivot, which obviously has to have the same type of the other
matrix entries.  Rather than providing a extra variable to play the role
of the pivot, which would inevitably require the matrix type to be
revealed, the solution is to allow quicksort to acess one unused matrix
entry, say entry n+1.  One more entry, namely n+2, is then used as
the auxiliary variable for swaping.